# How to trigger an event for select onselect

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I have a drop down select options. How to trigger an event when an option is selected.

Answer (score 3):

Prototype can `observe` a select element: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/

```
$('[element ID]').observe('change', function(){
   alert('foo bar');
});
```

Comment: Suppose I have a custom event 'My_Custom_Event', that needs to be triggered when an option is selected. How to do this, if my select menu is in 'template/catalog/product/list.phtml' ?

Comment: You could observe the `mouseover` event on the dropdown menu